# FQL photos from album get orginal image url

Tags: facebook-fql

I am using following FQL query to fetch all photos of a users..

```
SELECT src_big  FROM photo WHERE aid IN (SELECT aid FROM album WHERE owner=me())
```

But unfortunately the photos urls returned are of resized, the *_n.jpg urls... So, could any one please get me the way to fetch orginal photo urls (*_o.jpg) using FQL?

Answer (score 0):

Found it... query images field

```
   SELECT images  FROM photo WHERE aid IN (SELECT aid FROM album WHERE owner=me())
```

The zeroth index returned would have the high quality photo url...